# Building Boost Python Debug

Tags: python, boost, python-3.x, boost-python, python-embedding

I am definitely not a `bjam` expert, so pardon my ignorance if it's something really stupid.

I am trying to build a `debug` version of `boost::python` using [this tutorial](http://www.mantidproject.org/Building_Boost_Python).

I have built `Python 3.3.0` in my folder `C:\Development\Python-3.3.0`. The build is valid, the `.lib`, `.dll` and `.exe` are all present in the `PCBuild` folder. I tested the interpreter and it works properly.

I am using the following command line:

```
bjam --user-config=user-config.jam --with-python python-debugging=on threading=multi variant=debug link=shared stage
```

My issue comes from `user-config.jam`. I tried following the specifications of the tutorial, using the following:

```
using python : 3.3 : C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\PCBuild\\python_d.exe
    : C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\Include C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\PC
    : C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\PCBuild
    : <python-debugging>on ;
```

But the linking fails... for some reason, it doesn't seem to pick up that I want it to use 3.3, here's a part of the output log:

```
...updating 10 targets...
msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\debug\python-debugging-on\threa
ding-multi\boost_python-vc110-mt-gyd-1_52.dll
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python26_d.lib'

        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.b
at" x86 >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /subsystem:console /out:"b
in.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\debug\python-debugging-on\threading-multi\boos
t_python-vc110-mt-gyd-1_52.dll" /IMPLIB:"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\debu
g\python-debugging-on\threading-multi\boost_python-vc110-mt-gyd-1_52.lib" /LIBPA
TH:"C:\Development\Python-3.3.0\PCBuild"   @"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\
debug\python-debugging-on\threading-multi\boost_python-vc110-mt-gyd-1_52.dll.rsp
"
```

I tried making modifications to the `user-config.jam`. At first, I didn't escape the `\`, and surprisingly, it was detecting that I wanted to build 3.3 but the `/LIBPATH` was wrong (no backslashes):

```
...updating 10 targets...
msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\debug\python-debugging-on\threa
ding-multi\boost_python-vc110-mt-gyd-1_52.dll
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python33_d.lib'

        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.b
at" x86 >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /subsystem:console /out:"b
in.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\debug\python-debugging-on\threading-multi\boos
t_python-vc110-mt-gyd-1_52.dll" /IMPLIB:"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\debu
g\python-debugging-on\threading-multi\boost_python-vc110-mt-gyd-1_52.lib" /LIBPA
TH:"C:DevelopmentPython-3.3.0PCBuild"   @"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\deb
ug\python-debugging-on\threading-multi\boost_python-vc110-mt-gyd-1_52.dll.rsp"
```

As you can see, it's looking for `python33_d.lib`, which is what is desired, but `/LIBPATH` doesn't contain the `\`. I also tried replacing with `/` which again goes back to trying to link `python26_d.lib`.

If it can be useful, I uninstalled any previously installed version of Python.

How can I make my `jam` file properly require the version 3.3 and provide the right paths?

**Edit:** Playing a bit more around, I removed the "space" before the `;`... just doing that makes it look for the right version `3.3`, but it's trying to link the release version from a relative `libs` folder... worst case I wouldn't mind copying the libs from `PCBuild` to `libs`

```
using python : 3.3 : C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\PCBuild\\python_d.exe
    : C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\Include C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\PC
    : C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\PCBuild
    : <python-debugging>on;
```

The funny part is that it's the closest to what I'm trying to achieve, but it outputs

```
C:\Development\boost_1_52_0\boost_1_52_0\user-config.jam:4: syntax error at EOF
```

The `jam` parser seems pretty weak... any hints or tip would be helpful

**Edit 2:** trying to simplify the problem, I changed my `user-config.jam` to contain nothing but:

```
using python : 3.3 ;
```

And use the following command line:

```
bjam --user-config=user-config.jam --with-python threading=multi variant=release link=shared stage
```

As expected, it can't find the `.lib`

```
...updating 4 targets...
msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\boost_p
ython3-vc110-mt-1_52.dll
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'python33.lib'

        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.b
at" x86 >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /subsystem:console /out:"bin.v2\l
ibs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc110-mt-1_52.d
ll" /IMPLIB:"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\boost_py
thon3-vc110-mt-1_52.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Development\Python-3.3.0\libs"   @"bin.v2\
libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc110-mt-1_52.
dll.rsp"
```

So I decided to clone my `PCBuild` folder into `libs` so that all the libs I built would be accessible... but after doing so, without changing the `.jam` or the command line... it's now looking for Python 2.6?!?

```
...updating 4 targets...
msvc.link.dll bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\boost_p
ython3-vc110-mt-1_52.dll
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python26.lib'

        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\vcvarsall.b
at" x86 >nul
link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /subsystem:console /out:"bin.v2\l
ibs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc110-mt-1_52.d
ll" /IMPLIB:"bin.v2\libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\boost_py
thon3-vc110-mt-1_52.lib" /LIBPATH:"C:\Development\Python-3.3.0\libs"   @"bin.v2\
libs\python\build\msvc-11.0\release\threading-multi\boost_python3-vc110-mt-1_52.
dll.rsp"
```

The more I dig in, the more confused I am... also, one fails with a `LNK1104` and the other one with `LNK1181`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I ended up deciding to strip all the possible parameters from `bjam` and build from the start. I finally got `bjam` to build every target possible using this command line:

```
 bjam --user-config=user-config.jam --with-python
```

Where `user-config.jam` only contains the following:

```
using python : 3.3 : C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\PCBuild\\python.exe
    : C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\Include C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\PC
    : C:\\Development\\Python-3.3.0\\PCBuild : ;
```

It **seems** to be working properly now.

Thanks